# Bulma - Show Uncollapsed Navbar on Tablet

Tags: css, responsive-design, bulma

In the following runnable code snippet I have setup a basic Bulma layout with a navbar.  The navbar is breaking to hamburger very early for the amount/size of links I have.

How can I make this break on smaller screens only? e.g. Hamburger only on phones.

```js
(function() {
  let burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
  let nav = document.querySelector('#' + burger.dataset.target);

  burger.addEventListener('click', function() {
    burger.classList.toggle('is-active');
    nav.classList.toggle('is-active');
  });
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Hello Bulma!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.1/css/bulma.min.css">
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/js/all.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar is-black is-desktop">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-brand">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-item">
            title
          </a>
        <span class="navbar-burger burger" data-target="navMenu">
            <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div id="navMenu" class="navbar-menu">
        <div class="navbar-end">
          <a href="#" class="navbar-item is-active">Home</a>
          <a href="#" class="navbar-item">Two</a>
          <a href="#" class="navbar-item">Three</a>
          <a href="#" class="navbar-item">Four</a>
          <a href="#" class="navbar-item">Five</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <section class="section">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="title">
        Hamburger Help!
      </h1>
      <p class="subtitle">
        How do i get the nav links to show on tablet instead of the hamburger?
      </p>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set `$navbar-breakpoint` variable to tablet. By default navbar breakpoint is set to desktop.

In your main.scss, update Bulma's `$navbar-breakpoint` variable.

```
// Import only what you need from Bulma
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/utilities/_all.sass";
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/base/_all.sass";
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/elements/button.sass";
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/elements/container.sass";
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/elements/form.sass";
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/elements/title.sass";

$navbar-breakpoint: $tablet;

@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/components/navbar.sass";
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/layout/hero.sass";
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/layout/section.sass";
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/grid/columns.sass";
```

I'm setting `$navbar-breakpoint` variable to the value of `$tablet` after importing _all.sass utilities. You need to do that because `$tablet` variable has to get set first.

After that you need to set`$navbar-breakpoint` variable before importing navbar component, otherwise default desktop value will be used.