# How to change the nav breakpoint by CSS only in Bulma?

Tags: css, bulma

**UPDATE:**

I created a feature request on GitHub, you can track [here](https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/issues/2259).

---

I am using [Bulma](https://bulma.io/). Right now the navbar collapse and change to a burger menu when the width is less than 1088px. I hope to make it collapse only when less than around 768px or even smaller.

I read the [responsive document](https://bulma.io/documentation/modifiers/responsive-helpers/) but still cannot find a CSS only way to change it.

I hope to find a way overwrite without changing the Bulma source code. Any idea? Thanks

<kbd>[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g6du8xc9/)</kbd>

```
<nav class="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
  <div class="navbar-brand">
    <a class="navbar-item" href="https://bulma.io">
      <img src="https://bulma.io/images/bulma-logo.png" width="112" height="28">
    </a>

    <a role="button" class="navbar-burger burger" aria-label="menu" aria-expanded="false" data-target="navbarBasicExample">
      <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div id="navbarBasicExample" class="navbar-menu">
    <div class="navbar-start">
      <a class="navbar-item">
        Home
      </a>

      <a class="navbar-item">
        Documentation
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: There is a way to set a variable without overwriting source code. Please take a look at my answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52467626/bulma-show-uncollapsed-navbar-on-tablet/53527864#53527864

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to accept [sass/scss](https://sass-lang.com/guide#example-3-sass) (with an additional compilation step compared to really pure CSS), then you can just do, for example

```
/* Keep the menu visible on most but the smallest devices
 * @devdoc Must be applied before the bulma.sass is used, because this is used there */
$navbar-breakpoint: 320px;
```

See [how I use it in one of my projects](https://github.com/suterma/replayer-pwa/blob/b42a558f523e9bc8864206cacbeaf13c199be4a3/sass/replayer-styles.scss#L9).

Otherwise, you need to go with the solution by @Yash Soni

Answer (score 0):

first you need to find its css file

for example its docs.min.css

then such code :-

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1088px) {
    .navbar,.navbar-end,.navbar-menu,.navbar-start {
        align-items:stretch;
        display: flex
    }
```

^^^ this code does the modifications when screen goes below 1088

there are multiple css code in that file which starts with this:-

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1088px)
```

so, you need to find them all and replace with

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px)
```

that's all, task done on css level :)

Comment: Thanks, however, is there a way to overwrite without changing the bulma source code?

Comment: not specifically, but you can do some tweaks, like you can create your custom css for 768px and use it in one page and the normal one (1088px) for others

Comment: @HongboMiao You could include your modification AFTER including bulma, then your rules will overwrite bulma's (if they have the same specificity)